# How can I check for folders that have ONLY List access?

Tags: c#, file, filesystems

I've written a segment of code to check for folders that have the following permissions setup:

[image: Folder with ONLY list access]

Note that the user does not have read&execute, read, etc. All they have is "List Folder Contents." And this is the way we need it to be.

However, when I scan for this specific user in these folders, I cannot find this situation. It ALWAYS shows that they have read access (the ability to read a file within the folder) even though they clearly do not.

What am I doing wrong? Below I've put in comments about debug settings for the person pictured above.

```
internal bool IsListOnlyUser(string userID, string pth, bool IncludeInherited)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(pth);
    DirectorySecurity ds = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);

    AuthorizationRuleCollection acl = ds.GetAccessRules(true,
            IncludeInherited, typeof(NTAccount));

    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule ace in acl)
    {
        if (ace.IdentityReference.Value.ToString().ToLower() 
            == userID.ToLower())
        {
            FileSystemRights R2 = ace.FileSystemRights;

            // *** The rights for the user with LIST only are:
            //FileSystemRights.ReadData (same value as ListDirectory)
            //FileSystemRights.ReadExtendedAttributes
            //FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile (same value as Traverse)
            //FileSystemRights.ReadAttributes
            //FileSystemRights.ReadPermissions
            //FileSystemRights.Synchronize

            bool L = CheckRights(ace, FileSystemRights.ListDirectory);

            bool R = CheckRights(ace, FileSystemRights.Read);
            // Yet, this resolves to TRUE! But I tested. This guy does NOT 
            // have access to the files themselves. Only to the fact that 
            // the file exists.

            bool W = CheckRights(ace, FileSystemRights.Modify);
            // This still resolves to FALSE

            if (L && !R && !W)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private bool CheckRights(FileSystemAccessRule ACE, FileSystemRights fileSystemRights)
{
    bool r = ((ACE.FileSystemRights & fileSystemRights) == fileSystemRights) &&
        (ACE.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow);

    return r;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As a side note, the "IncludeInherited" is always false in my testing, but this problem holds true no matter which way I turn the inheritance flag.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning you may want to take a look at the actual meaning of each FileSystemRights enumeration value [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights.aspx) because it looks based on your comments that by giving the user some of the rights that they have you are inadvertently giving them read access.

Comment: I've checked with the user. They do NOT have any more access than we intended for them to have. It's just that my search program THINKS they do. I've actually sat at their physical keyboard and tried to read files, copy files, etc. The rights for the user are correct. And Yes, I know that the rights flags are used and re-used so there is cross-contamination there. But in this case, I'm doing very basic windows security settings.